# how to call method from activity in another class

Tags: android

i need to get method from appcompatactivity to this class and call this method in another appcaompatactity like this

```
public class WareHouseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_warehouse);

}
 public void showToast(){

        Toast.makeText(WareHouseActivity.this,"warehouse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

call method showToast from appcampatactivity in this class :

```
public class Common {

    public static void showToast(Activity activity){

        ((WareHouseActivity)activity).showToast();
    }
}
```

and i try with context instead of using Activity like:

```
public class Common {

    public static void showToast(Context context){

        ((WareHouseActivity)context).showToast();
    }
}
```

call method showToast from class in another appcompatactivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_warehouse);

    Common.showToast(MainActity.this);

}

}
```

Comment: this seems like a really bad practice and for something so simple as showing a toast, why not just add the code to where you need it ?

Comment: i put it for example , actually i need to get parameters from activity to another activty so i will be  follow this idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a method with multiple Activities, it cannot live on an Activity instance. You can't be guaranteed that the instance exists when another Activity is being shown, and you should never create Activity instances yourself.

If you move the full method to a separate class like this:

```java
public class Common {
    // You must pass in any arguments needed in the function
    public static void showToast(Context context){
        Toast.makeText(context,"warehouse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from any activity

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_warehouse);

    Common.showToast(this);
}
```

**Update**

If the reason you want to do this is to have shared data that you can access from both activities, that data should not live in one of the activities. Have a look at the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), activities will be destroyed when the device is rotated, or can be destroyed when in the background by the OS. Any temporary data you store on an activity would be lost when that happens.

One simple option for storing some temporary data is a singleton class. This is not persistent - the data will still be lost if your app is stopped and restarted). If you need persistent data you should use SharedPreferences or a database for that. However, it will let some temporary data live longer than an individual activity's lifecycle and be accessible from multiple activities or fragments.

```java
class Common {
    private static Common instance = null;
    private Common() {}

    public static synchronized Common getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Common();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    String message = "";

    void showMessage(Context ctx) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Then you can set and use data stored in this class from multiple activities, like this

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Common c = Common.getInstance();
        c.message = "Hello from Main";
        c.names.add("Test");
    }
}
```

```java
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Common c = Common.getInstance();
        c.showMessage(this)
        c.names.add("Test Two");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but This is not my question. my question is I want to invoke a function from activity to another activity so i use this way for example

Comment: Like I said, you cannot and should not do that. Activities can be created and destroyed by the system and you have no reliable way of keeping an instance of the one you want to call available. If you need shared parameters you should store them outside any activity. If you add an example of the kind of parameters you want to share I can show some options.

Comment: @شاكرنيال I added some details about how to use this pattern to store data in a common location that is accessible to multiple activities.

Comment: yes like this , call insert method (which insert to database) from close activity to my open activity to insert an object to its entity ,so i don't need to open activity only call method insert from it which exict in viewmodel