# how to get method from activity to class in android .java

Tags: android

i need to get method insert from warehouse activity to insert object from another activity so i use class hold insert function to provid it to the mainactivity which i will be add object through it

insert fun in warehouse activity

```
 public void insert(WareHouseEntity wareHouseEntity){

        warehouseViewModel.insert(wareHouseEntity);
    }
```

i call insert fun in this common class

```
public class Common{
public static void insertWareHouse(WareHouseEntity wareHouseEntity){

        WareHouseActivity wareHouseActivity=new WareHouseActivity();
        wareHouseActivity.insert(wareHouseEntity);
    }
}
```

and i try add object to Warehosue entity by mainactivity so i call insert method from class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Common.insertWareHouse(new WareHouseEntity());

}

}
```

Comment: not sure why [you're asking on different accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740235/how-to-call-method-from-activity-in-another-class?noredirect=1#comment126783878_71740235), but again, using this idea of a common class is probably not going to work like you want it to, using `WareHouseActivity wareHouseActivity=new WareHouseActivity();` isn't a good idea

Comment: I would suggest you create a new class for insertion or create a view model.